# Jwt Authentication: JwtTokenBuilder

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently new on ASP.net,I find it hard to implement a token authentication(Jwt),I have been following this example : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-2-0-bearer-authentication/

So I got lost along the way`

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Credential inputModel)
    {
        if (inputModel.Username != "mgiba" && inputModel.Password != "tech")
            return Unauthorized();

        var token = new JwtTokenBuilder()
                            .AddSecurityKey(JwtSecurityKey.Create("fiversecret "))
                            .AddSubject("mgiba tech")
                            .AddIssuer("Fiver.Security.Bearer")
                            .AddAudience("Fiver.Security.Bearer")
                            .AddClaim("MembershipId", "111")
                            .AddExpiry(1)
                            .Build();

        return Ok(token.Value);
    }
```

It doesn't pick up JWtTokenBulder() class,So I am no longer sure if I supposed to create the class "JwtTokenBuilder" from the scratch or It suppose to co`enter code here`me with a specific namespace/library

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: you can use the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` to create the JWT

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407688/core-2-0-api-auth-with-jwt-returns-unauthorized?noredirect=1#comment89820755_51407688

Comment: check the implementation here https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore-jwt-sample/blob/master/website/TokenGenerator.cs